# Javafx AlwaysOnTop windows priority on macos full screen application

Tags: java, macos, javafx, java-8

I can't find anything on this and i am not sure if this is even possible but i will try. I have a JavaFX application showing a stage when you start typing text (it listen to os inputs). Everything is working fine except when the application is set to full screen on macOS. The stage will not show over the application, even if alwaysontop is true.

Only way i got this to work was using a JDialog in Type.POPUP but this is causing other issues in my code. I tried playing with the window level but it doesn't work.

Here is a test i ran to test the issue. This will go over any application except when it is in full screen.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class ontopTest extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage){
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(new Label("test application")));
    stage.setTitle("test");
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setWidth(300);
    stage.setHeight(300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    // stage.setAlwaysOnTop unneeded as com.sun.glass.ui sets window to top
    stage.setY(0); // Set Y Axis to 0
    // Need to show window first
    stage.show();

    com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).setLevel(3);
    // Set window level to 3 (Maximum)
 }
}
```

I want to know if this is possible with JavaFX or any other workaround. I want my view to be over any application, even full screen.

Comment: “The view will not show over the application” What view?  I gather you’re trying to show some sort of overlay as the user types, but without a [mcve] that lets me see the problem for myself, I don’t know what to suggest.  I do know that using a com.sun class is going to prevent you from using versions of Java later than 10, and quite possibly versions later than 8.

Comment: I know, the com.sun glass was to show that even the highest possible level is not showing over the full screen application. I mean the stage when talking about the view sorry. If you run my MCVE, a 300/300 stage will appear above applications except when full screen mode on macOS.